# Removing some paragraph marks in a word document

Tags: ms-word

I copy text from PDF files into word 2010 documents using Abbyy conversion software. I find the result will contain many line breaks which are incorrect. Is there any way I can remove any such marks if they are not preceded by either "." or "?" or "!"
I write macros in excel but have no experience of word coding

Answer (score 0):

You could do a search and replace depending if you can find some sort of rules wich you can apply. Mayeby a little screenshot?